# Windowshade-like animation hiding cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-animation

I have the following table view, several section headers with a button to allow hiding/showing the section. I have been asked to hide the section by scrolling the section's cells up until the section is closed (leaving section headers visible of source). Without animations this is easy, I just have to set the cells height to 0 and they vanish on reload. I'm not sure how to do this with the window shade type animation. On tapping Category0 I want Sample0-Sample3 appear to roll up under the header as the rest of the table moves up.

I could create a single cell which has a fixed-height table embedded in it to avoid having to do multiple cells if there is no other way.

I am writing this in Swift but either language is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would take some tinkering to work this out, but you may be able to use UIView block-based animation to animate the cells away.

The first thing you could do is simply animate the center position of all the cells in the section up by the same amount so that the bottom of the bottom cell lines up with the bottom of the section header. At the end of the animation remove the extra cells and call reloadData on the table view and it will redisplay to match the animation. The problem with that approach is that the cells will not disappear under the section header. You will probably need to add a mask to each cell's layer that exposes the area of the sections cells but masks away everything else.

You might not be able to get away with using UIView animation and might have to use Core Animation instead.  You'd add mask layers to each cell's layer, do the animation on the cells' layers' positions, update your model, call the table view's reloadData, then remove the masks from the cells' layers and set their positions back to normal so they aren't displaced when they are recycled.

Comment: Yeah the biggest problem is hiding the table's normal behavior. Right now I have it working with a simple UIView animation, which doesn't look all that bad to me, but if this becomes a has to be requirement, I will try using core animation. Will update as I know more.